Horizontal Bar chart: cut off top and bottom bars
I have the problem, that somehow the bars at the top and bottom are cut off when compiling them. The red one above with 421 and the blue one below which is 0 are not visible. I am quite new to latex, so I would appreciate your help!
Thank you very much!

This is my code:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        bar width=0.25cm,
        width=14cm,
        height=13cm,
        enlarge x limits={abs={100}},
        legend style={at={(0.9,0.15)}, anchor=north},
        xlabel={x},
        symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=750,
        y dir=reverse,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
     
        \addplot coordinates {(225,A) (550,B) (226,C) (4,D) (260,E) (73,F) (51,G) (56,H) (65,I) (146,J) (50,K) (77,L) (0,M)};
        
     
        \addplot coordinates {(421,A) (331,B) (426,C) (0,D) (703,E) (489,F) (664,G) (310,H) (272,I) (38,J) (0,K) (139,L) (115,M)};
        
        \legend{X, Y}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


With enlarge y limits, but after axis y line=left.
Remark:Next time, give a compilable document, it starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        bar width=0.25cm,
        width=14cm,
        height=13cm,
        enlarge x limits={abs={100}},
        legend style={at={(0.9,0.15)}, anchor=north},
        xlabel={x},
        symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=750,
        y dir=reverse,
        axis y line=left,
        enlarge y limits,%<--- this line
        axis x line=bottom,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        ]
    
        \addplot coordinates {(225,A) (550,B) (226,C) (4,D) (260,E) (73,F) (51,G) (56,H) (65,I) (146,J) (50,K) (77,L) (0,M)};
        
    
        \addplot coordinates {(421,A) (331,B) (426,C) (0,D) (703,E) (489,F) (664,G) (310,H) (272,I) (38,J) (0,K) (139,L) (115,M)};
        
        \legend{X, Y}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you a lot! This works! :) And thanks for the advice!

You are welcome
